# Using the aws cognito UserInfo endpoint

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, http, authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to call this User endpoint from my django rest framework backend server.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/userinfo-endpoint.html

According to the documentation I need to make a GET request with an authorization bearer token.
so from my backend I have tried:

'''
requests.get('https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/oauth2/userInfo',headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+str(request.auth)[2:-1]})
'''

where the splicing at the end is just getting rid of the b' and the ' around the access token from django rest framework's request.auth.

I get nothing back or a 400 bad request, but not the one that the documentation says I should get.

I've also tried this from postman in various ways. [Here's one of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REqSk.png)

Any help on the proper formatting of this request would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your user pool domain:

`https://{{user_pool_domain}}.auth.{{region}}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userinfo`